# Nearest intersection point to the center of multiple spheres

Tags: 3d, spheres, intersection-theory

I have multiple spheres with the same radius *r*, and I need to find the nearest intersection point to the center of all the spheres. I also know that all the spheres intersect together.
I'm using geogebra for visualizing the spheres and any formula or script that works here fine.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Three spheres intersect in two points. Try all triples of spheres and find the nearest sphere center. An $O(n^4)$ process.